# Use the squeezing theorem to find the limit of the sequence $\cos(n)/n!$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

Is anyone able to help me answer this question? Or point me in the right direction?

> Use the squeezing theorem to find the limit of the sequence $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ with $n$-th term $a_n=\dfrac{\cos(n)}{n!}$.

Answer (score 3):

$-1\leq\cos{n}\leq 1$ so $$\frac{-1}{n!}\leq\frac{\cos{n}}{n!}\leq\frac{1}{n!}$$ holds for every n, and then take the limit.

Comment: $\cos n$ can be negative

Comment: Fixed that! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

-1 < cosn < 1 ==> -1/n! < cosn/n! < 1/n!. Next 0 < 1/n! < 1/n and clearly lim (1/n) = 0. So squeeze theorem gives: lim (1/n!) = 0. This means lim ( -1/n!) = 0. So squeeze theorem again says: lim cosn/n! = 0.